# How to handle RemoteException when sending message during IPC?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, ipc, android-service-binding

I'm using the `Messenger` and `Handler` to send messages between service and client. The code is almost exactly the same as [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample).

I'm not sure how to handle the `RemoteException` as I assume I should have some kind of retry logic? I tried to kill the service process but still no RemoteException is caught. So should I do a retry logic in this catch, or where is the best place I could do a retry since the message is not sent yet?

```
private final static Messenger MESSENGER = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler()); 

public static void callService(final int command, final Bundle args) {
    try {
        final Message message = Message.obtain(null, command);
        message.replyTo = MESSENGER;

        if (args != null) {
            message.setData(args);
        }
        serviceMsgr.send(message);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The service has crashed.", e);
    }
}

static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received from service: " + msg.what);

        switch (msg.what) {
            case xxxx:
                 ...;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I tried to kill the service process but still no RemoteException is caught" -- what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry I mis-explained. So I tried to kill the package that this service lives in, but now I assume this won't cause any RemoteException then? Do you know when this exception will be caught? Should I do anything about it?

Comment: "So I tried to kill the package that this service lives in" -- no offense, but I do not understand that either. What **exactly** are you doing? The simplest way that I know of to terminate a process is to kill it from Android Studio. I would expect that if you are bound to a service, and the service's process is terminated, that you would get the `RemoteException`.

Comment: Ok, so if this is the case, should put some retry logic to the catch block? Otherwise, where is the best place to put retry?

Comment: I cannot answer that. If you get a `RemoteException`, you have to assume that you need to get a fresh `Messenger`. I do not know where your code is for that, whether that makes sense to do from `callService()`, etc. For all I know, your app has no way of triggering the other app to send you its `Messenger`, in which case you may not have an obvious retry path.

Comment: The messenger is a final static one initiated with a handler. I'm updating the code in the post.

Comment: Well, `serviceMsgr` is the `Messenger` of importance. That's the one whose `send()` might throw the `RemoteException`. And that's the one that you need to replace, if you get a `RemoteException`.

Comment: Ok cool Thanks. The serviceMsgr is initiated in doBindService() so I might need to redo this. Do you know if onServiceConnected() from ServiceConnection interface will be called automatically to recoonect?

Comment: I doubt that it will, but I haven't experimented with this scenario much recently.